# How to run process in background and get its pid to create log file name

Tags: shell-script

When I do

```
node process.js 1>$LOGFOLDER\\$$.log
```

the created process's `PID` become the filename. I want to run this process in the background as I want to run many instances of the same `process.js`. So, I added `&` at the end,

```
node process.js 1>$LOGFOLDER\\$$.log &
```

This made the process to run in the background but the `PID`(the filename) is always wrong. I did log the process id using `$!` after the above line. In first case both `$!`'s output and logfile's name are same. But in second case they are not. Making the process to run in background using `&` is giving different `PID` in the `$$` placeholder. Why is this happening and how can I make the both work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the backgrounded process runs in a subshell. To do what you want you could do this:

```
LOGFOLDER="$LOGFOLDER" bash -c 'node process.js 1>$LOGFOLDER.$$.log' &
```

Comment: Oh Thanks. But this one is not executing the `process.js`. No file is created and no error logs

Comment: @RaR: It's those single quotes. Look at my edited answer for a resolution. HTH.

Comment: Without `LOGFOLDER` being exported  (I see the edit does this in the one-line format) then it's set to nothing in the subshell; if you do an `ls -a` then you'll see the log file as a hidden `.12345.log` file in the current directory (if you have write access to it)